# Java type that holds two primitives of any primitive type

Tags: java, types

I want to store two primitive values (and I'm including `String` as a primitive here) inside a field. For example, I may want to store a `String` and an `int` as below:

```
("hello", 42)
```

So if the type I'm looking for is `X`, I'd like to be able to declare a field

```
private X myX = new X("hello", 42);
```

or some other incantation that gives me the same result.

I'm trying to figure out what type that field has to be. It has to accept any Java primitive type and `String` so it could be a `String` + `int` or `String` + `float`... actually any combination of primitive (+ `String`) types. Essentially, to borrow a concept from functional languages, I just want a `tuple` that's restricted to primitives. But Java doesn't have that.

Since they are primitives, generics don't work very well. And I'm not sure how I feel about boxing/unboxing.

What is the best data type/structure I can use in Java to do it?

Comment: what do you mean by "all types"? All primitive types + string (int, boolean, short, float, etc...) or all objects too?

Comment: Nop just primitive types

Comment: HashMap<String,Object> ?

Comment: Ok I will edit sorry for the confusion

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to achieve... And this kind of "all types" mechanisms are always kind of ugly to work with!

Comment: Yes that's always 2 values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to store the values as one primitive type, you have to 'encode' them.

For example:

```
String field = "hello;42";
String[] values = field.split(";");
int intValue = Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think that there is a way to do it with built-in Java libraries. However one could write Tuple class identical to Tuple2 class in Scala language like this:

```
public class Tuple<K, V> {
        private K first;
        private V second;

        // create tuple only with static method "of"
        private Tuple(K first, V second) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;

        }

        public static <K, V> Tuple<K, V> of(K a, V b) {
            return new Tuple<K, V>(a, b);
        }

        public Tuple<V, K> swap() {
            return new Tuple<V, K>(second, first);
        }

        public K getFirst() {
            return this.first;
        }

        public V getSecond() {
            return this.second;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + first.toString() + "," + second.toString() + ")";
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Tuple myTuple = Tuple.of("hello", 2);

            System.out.println("toString: "+myTuple);
            System.out.println("First: "+myTuple.getFirst());
            System.out.println("Swap: "+ myTuple.swap());
        }

    }

    Output:

    toString: (hello,2)
    First: hello
    Swap: (2,hello)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're working with only primitives (and `String`) it seems that you'd like to avoid auto-boxing and unboxing if possible. That means you can't use generics. (Primitive types can't be used as type arguments.) It also seems as though you'd like to avoid unnecessary promotion (e.g. if you stored `floats` as `doubles` you'd preserve the original value, but lose the fact that it's actually a `float`).

A rather elaborate solution would be to create a set of `PrimitivePair` classes, one for each combination of primitive types that you want to store, along with a factory class for constructing them easily. For example, you might have the following three classes to store various pairs of primitives:

```
package primitivepair;

public class PrimitivePairStringInt
{
   final String s;
   final int i;

   PrimitivePairStringInt(final String s, final int i)
   {
      this.s = s;
      this.i = i;
   }

   public String getFirstValue()
   {
      return s;
   }

   public int getSecondValue()
   {
      return i;
   }
}
```

---

```
package primitivepair;

public class PrimitivePairFloatDouble
{
   final float f;
   final double d;

   PrimitivePairFloatDouble(final float f, final double d)
   {
      this.f = f;
      this.d = d;
   }

   public float getFirstValue()
   {
      return f;
   }

   public double getSecondValue()
   {
      return d;
   }
}
```

---

```
package primitivepair;

public class PrimitivePairCharByte
{
   final char c;
   final byte b;

   PrimitivePairCharByte(final char c, final byte b)
   {
      this.c = c;
      this.b = b;
   }

   public char getFirstValue()
   {
      return c;
   }

   public byte getSecondValue()
   {
      return b;
   }
}
```

They would be created by the following factory class:

```
package primitivepair;

public class PrimitivePairFactory
{
   public static PrimitivePairCharByte createPrimitivePair(final char c, final byte b)
   {
      return new PrimitivePairCharByte(c, b);
   }

   public static PrimitivePairFloatDouble createPrimitivePair(final float f, final double d)
   {
      return new PrimitivePairFloatDouble(f, d);
   }

   public static PrimitivePairStringInt createPrimitivePair(final String s, final int i)
   {
      return new PrimitivePairStringInt(s, i);
   }
}
```

You can of course add more classes and factory methods for other combinations.

I wanted to make an abstract `PrimitivePair` class that would have the creation methods *and* method declarations for the `getFirstValue()` and `getSecondValue()` methods, but that would have required that return type covariance works for primitives, and I don't believe it does.

Answer (score 0):

Java does not have a built-in Tuple type.

You might use the standard [Map.Entry<K,V>](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) but I would personally suggest Apache Commons Lang3's Tuple type if possible.